# How can i make my program run automatically in python

Tags: python-2.7

I export my python code by pyinstaller i need my program to startup automatically whith the windows (i don't need to do that by startup folder)

Comment: What have you found out so far? Let us not waste time on things you already tried (except, of course, you pay us with money)

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I search it before i post my question, i start with this file hello.py then i make it hello.exe by pyinstaller 1.5.1 my python is 2.7 exe to run automatically with the windows ( Sorry if my englash are bad )

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a shortcut. This will create shortcut on your desktop

```
import os, sys
import pythoncom
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

shortcut = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance (
shell.CLSID_ShellLink,
  None,
  pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
  shell.IID_IShellLink
)
shortcut.SetPath (sys.executable)
shortcut.SetDescription ("Python %s" % sys.version)
shortcut.SetIconLocation (sys.executable, 0)

desktop_path = shell.SHGetFolderPath (0, shellcon.CSIDL_DESKTOP, 0, 0)
persist_file = shortcut.QueryInterface (pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile)
persist_file.Save (os.path.join (desktop_path, "python.lnk"), 0)
```

You can make toany of windows locations for startup files ( or create it only in startup place) :

- Run Once :HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
- Run each Start: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- StartUp folder : C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
- Shared Task Manager : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SharedTaskScheduler
- Make it as a service, and make that service automatic started

To see what programs start automatically on your computer, or to add your entries easy, you can use **autoruns** from SysInternals,
 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

P.S. Python example is from timgolden.me.uk site.

Comment: Thank you but i still need a python code that makes this for me

Comment: Your question were too bad explained, so you didnt got an exact answer. Check again, i added some stuff.

Comment: Thank you again let me explan to you my file is file.exe when some on click it i need  the file alweys startup with the windows .... your new add is nice i like it